# Is it possible to pass url parameters to google play? (pass query strings)

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

Is it possible to pass url parameters (or "query strings") to google play and track the variable while installing the app in phone?

Comment: I don't think its is possible. but why you are doing so.

Comment: My app users will download this app from their franchisee's website.App  store link will be in that site. Franchisee site owners will  put franchisee unique id along with google play address (eg:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&franchiseeid=USAFLO012) This will help the installed app to show unique logo , contact address and phone number , if it can atach the url parameter franchiseeid.

Comment: @Vinod what are you talking about? If I search for ["*inurl:franchiseeid site:play.google.com*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Afranchiseeid+site%3Aplay.google.com) I'll get no results.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-implement

Answer (score 13):

According to this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-how

How Google Play Campaign Measurement works

Google Play Store Campaign Measurement relies on the use of Campaign Parameters to **pass campaign and traffic source information into your app at the time that it is downloaded from the Google Play Store**.

The following is an end-to-end description of how Google Play Campaign Measurement works:

A user clicks on a link, from an ad, website, or app, that takes them to your app's Google Play Store page. The link is tagged with Campaign Parameters.
After the user downloads and installs your app, the Google Play Store will broadcast an INSTALL_REFERRER intent on the device that includes those same campaign parameters.
Your app will then respond to that intent, using the BroadcastReceiver object provided below, reading the campaign parameters and using them to update the Google Analytics campaign information.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns is the new new new version of this. Was wondering if you wanted to update your text to reflect the new method.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done by using an *install referrer* and listen to it in the app after install through an *InstallReferrerReceiver*: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver

In your case you can simply put your `franchiseeid` into the `referrer` property:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&referrer=franchiseeid%3DUSAFLO012`

This is a little late but might help others.

Answer (score 6):

If you route the parameters as part of the campaign tracking options in the Analytics SDK, it is possible to pass in custom variables to the installed application if the user follows a provided link.

For example, set the campaign name to a variable.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns

In my example, I set it to the users email address so when the app loads, the login form is prefilled.

Comment: Could you please share the example code for this implementation as this is not clear where to add custom parameter ?