# URL to Google Play or App Store with parameters

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I have website and now i am building mobile app for it. What i am trying to do is when user click download app from website i want to send username & password or authToken as parameter to store url like this

```
url_to_store/?token=token
```

so that after user downloads he/she doesn't need to login again.

Comment: There would be no relation as such between the url and need to login after download, one way to try could be you match an Id like Google account signed in - from website and when the app is launched, from device. This would still require some communication between your website and mobile app

Comment: @ user2450263 i just want to know, is it possible to pass parameters so i can retrieve in the app

Comment: no, that would not be possible

Comment: It is possible. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653944/is-it-possible-to-pass-url-parameters-to-google-play-pass-query-strings + 

https://n3vrax.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/listen-for-install-referrer-broadcast-message-get-referrer-on-install/

Comment: @PaMaDo what about ios ?

Comment: Sorry i am an Android guy. I have no idea how this could work on iOS.

Comment: @PaMaDo CampaignTracking is quite different actually, like..correct for only question statement, not his requirement or question