# Pass a specific query string from website through the app download and then back to web

Tags: php, android, ios

We are attempting to give a Gift Code which equals $X to our new Users.

If a User downloads our Webview apps (Android or iOS) the query string is not passed and the User is not credited with the gift.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653944/is-it-possible-to-pass-url-parameters-to-google-play-pass-query-strings) about 'INSTALL_REFERRER' but that doesn't seem to be appropriate. These all seem to only report for analytics and we would like the new User to receive the Gift Amount in their account after download and then Sign Up.

The code is pretty basic /giftlaunch.php?offer=20DONATION

After clicking this link the User is taken to the page and chooses to download an app or continue to website. Website works perfect but if User downloads, upon return the query string is no longer available to credit them.

How do I pass this through the App Download?

Answer (score 1):

From your web application, on click of the download button you could write to a file in a certain directory of the users device.

The contents of this file would be the key / value of your gift voucher, and an expiry date (e.g. in an hour).

On create of your application you can then attempt to read the contents of this file. If it exists, the content equals "giftlaunch.php?offer=20DONATION", and the expiry date hasn't passed, you can be confident the user followed that link to download the app.

Now you can handle the logic from within your applications, and you do not have to pass information through each store (App Store, Play Store, etc)...

Comment: I've found the suggestion to be difficult since the 'root' permission necessary is quite restrictive and difficult. I have thought perhaps we could from the "Landing Page" store an ID specific to that visitor using the email as a UID. Then when they return to the site and sign up this would be linked to the correct Promotion. I think we may lose a few people who have signed up to Social Media accounts using an email other than the original but conversion seems more likely than asking for root access.